# create another exact copy of a zope instance running along with data

Tags: python, plone, zope, zodb

Hi guys I'm quite new to zope and I have a situation where I have to clone the whole zope instance running along with data. I have already tried copying Data.fs to new zope instance but it didn't work. The version of zope I'm using is quite old(Zope - 2.10.6, Python - 2.4) . Can some one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the data.fs, thats not a problem. But the new setup should have similar versions of all packages. If you want to do an upgrade with the copy, you can setup a newer version, let's say the next major version. When this ist running, you can replace the data.fs with your copy. Also delete the data.fs.* files, as they need to be regenerated with the replaced data.fs.

If you tell us more about your errors, we might help you more.
Also tell us what you exactly want to archive.

Comment: Hi Tango,
Thanks for your kind reply. 
My exact need is to move the zope instance to new server running along with data. so I have installed zope(exact version in old server) in new server and created a new instance with it.So I have replaced the data.fs file, Extensions and Products folders from old zope instance. When I try to run instance it was not showing old data. So can you help me with this?

Comment: What Zope and Python version are you using?
So if i understand you right, you can start the copy instance but you don't see the data. double check the name of the Data.fs, make sur you delete the Data.fs index and tmp-files. The zope configuration should point to the Data.fs. Are you using zc.buildout or just plain Zope?

Comment: Hi Tango, My zope version is quite old(Zope - 2.10.6, Python - 2.4) and I'm using just plain zope. As per your suggestion I tried to run it after deleting temp files now It was throwing me an error that some module(report) is missing. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe provide the full stack, otherwise nobody can help ;)

Comment: My old instance is using Zope - 2.10.6, Python - 2.4 . Whole data was stored in postgres databse. Tango could you please describe me a process to move the zope instance to another server.

Comment: Please ask Zope or Plone questions in our forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you

Comment: if your Database was stored in postgress with relstorage, than you don't have a Data.fs file which contains your current data. In this case you have to make a copy of your PG database. But Kim is right, maybe ask in the forum, there e more people reading and some of them using relstorage, i don't.